# How to find the length of a line in any file without loading the line into memory?

Tags: java, xml, file, memory-management

I am writing a java program that works with 50-60GB files. One line of the file could be 2-3GB, and if loaded would break my JVM. I want to find the length of this line so I know whether this line can go into a DOM parser, or a SAX parser. Each line of this document is a separate XML. I have seem many ways to get the length, but they all involve loading them into memory to figure it out. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Ooof.  By putting multiple XML documents into one file - one XML document per line - processes are forced to read through the file to find out both how big each document is and where the next one starts.  And if you have or ever want to have either binary data or embedded text in the XML documents that could have line feeds embedded in them, you also have to parse each and every XML document just to find out where the next one is.  And you're saying just one line is such a file is big enough to crash your JVM?!?!

Comment: If I add one of the XML that is 2-3GB into the DOM it will crash the JVM, however that is why I need the length of that line. If the line length exceeds my threshold I will use my sax parser as to not crash my JVM.

Comment: Why not use the SAX parser all the time? Why have two sets of code, one for "small" and one for "large"?

Comment: Speed in the program is key. It needs to do as much as possible as fast as possible.

Answer (score 4):

Read some characters into a fixed sized buffer with [Reader.read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read(char[],%20int,%20int)) and then scan the buffer.

Comment: And hope the XML document doesn't have embedded linefeeds in it.

Comment: Yeah I agree the premise is insane. I'm just answering the question as asked.

Comment: And you pretty much nailed the only possible solution - dig through the haystack and examine each bit of hay to see if it's the next needle.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [LineNumberReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html):

```
public static long getLineCount(Reader reader)
throws IOException {
    LineNumberReader lineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader(reader);
    lineNumberReader.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    return lineNumberReader.getLineNumber();
}
```